# Adwords - Insert query string in dynamic insertion on destination URL

Tags: google-ads, google-ads-valuetrack

We are trying to best optimize a campaign on AdWords. We implemented the dynamic substitution on the final URL so we could pass KW data through on clic: `www.example.com/?keyword={keyword}`.

But doing so, we just send as data the paid KW that triggered the ad, while we actually would like to pass as a data on our string the actual query a user made on google, so, to be clear the values after the `q=` parameter.

For instance:

We bid for the KW "free" > the user searches for "free apples" > the data the destination URL will have to print should be: `www.example.com/?keyword=Value` in which value equals `q=`.

We tried to bypass the problem by making a direct API request to analytics (linked to Wm tools and AdWords) to get the query string in real time, but I guess we miss some values on how to achieve that.

Also we tried to analyze the referral URL but the `q=` parameter is empty.

Comment: Have you seen this : https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2549100?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the query that the user actually performed as part of Google AdWords.   Google used to pass this information in the refferer URL, but now hides the referrer in the vast majority of cases.

As you note the `{keyword}` value track parameter substitutes in the keyword you bid on.   The only time that will match the query exactly is when you bid on something as "exact match".  Other than only bidding as exact match and using `{keyword}`, Google does not make the data you are looking for available.